# facing issues with getting data

Tags: java, jsoup

I have one html page, i am trying to get data(text) from it. Facing below problem.

Following is the html page code

```html
<div class="main-class">
<div class="sub-class">
<p class="title">Title of data one</p>
<p>one data</p>
<p>two line</p>
<p> three line</p>
<ul>
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="sub-class">
<p class="title">Title of data two</p>
<p>asd sdffsdfsdf</p>
    <p>asd dfgdfg</p>
    <p>asd dfgdfgd</p>
    <ul>
    <li>qweqwe</li>
    <li>fghgfhgf</li>
    <li>gdfgdfgd</li>
    </ul>
    <p>new p tag</p>
    <table>ignore</table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

there is one main class two sub class.I am able to get the all the text from main-class. But need to store data from first sub class in one string and second sub class in another string. Need to ignore last p tag and table tag.

Condition is that some time there might not be first sub class.So data from second sub class must get in second string and first string is should be null.

I have tried the following code

```
Elements data = doc.getElementsByClass("sub-class");
    System.out.println(data);
    String allData= data .text();
```

I am getting all the text from sub class.

I am facing following issues
1. Not able to store first sub class data in String one= ?
2. Not able to store second sub-class data in String two= ?
3. Not able to get `<ul> <li> tag text data`.
4. Not able to ignore last `<p> tag and <table> tag`

```java
Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("main-class");
   Elements subClassData1 = document.select("div.sub-class:eq(0)");

    if(elements.hasText()){
      return elements.text().toString();
    }
    else if(subClassData1 != null){
      return subClassData1.text().toString();

      }

    }
```

Expected result is

Sub class one data = "*Title of data one : one data two line three line a b c*

Sub class two data = "*Title of data two : asd sdffsdfsdf asd dfgdfg asd fgdfgd
    qweqwe fghgfhgf gdfgdfgd*

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if you are looking for this, but this code below solves all 3 problems, tweak it as desired based on your conditions, approach follows:

Basically, you have 2 elements for 2 sub-class elements, and they can be iterated.
Also, for the second sub-class element, last two child elements can be removed.

```
    Document jsoupDocument = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8");
    Elements allSubClassElements = jsoupDocument.getElementsByClass("sub-class");
    System.out.println("Num of sub-classes found "+allSubClassElements.size());
    System.out.printf("First Subclass %s", allSubClassElements.get(0).text());
    System.out.println();
    Element secondSubClassElement = allSubClassElements.get(1);

    //want to remove last 2 elements
    for (int i = secondSubClassElement.children().size(), j = 0; j < 2; i--, j++) {
        //element would be updated here.
        secondSubClassElement.child(i - 1).remove();
    }
    System.out.printf("Second Subclass %s", secondSubClassElement.text());
```